# carrot2 pubmed read timed out

Tags: carrot2, pubmed

I just started using carrot2 directly today (I have previous experience using it as part of  @note2).

I am able to search the web and Wikipedia through either http://search.carrot2.org or the workbench application.

When searching the pubmed source, I get the following errors:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/130.14.29.110 timed out
```

Could they be transient or version dependent?  Is anyone else successfully searching and clustering pubmed records with carrot2?

Comment: Could you show some code and settings?

Comment: @Icewind I'm using all default settings for both the web interface and the workbench application, except setting the document source to pubmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on input from Dawid Weiss and Jack Park at http://sourceforge.net/p/carrot2/mailman/message/33066121/

NCBI puts various limitations on pubmed queries through http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/

They include time-of-day and per-IP limitations.  See http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25497/